# как во flutter передавать http запросы в свернутом приложении?

Tags: flutter, dart

в моем приложении курьер должен каждые 15 секунд передавать свои геоданные, но когда курьер берет заказ и открывает навигатор будто 2gis или yandex navigator, то в свернутом режиме этот запрос который передает геоданные не работает, что нужно прописывать что оно работало?

использую `dio` для запросов и `getx` для `state management`a

Answer (score 0):

В [данной статье](https://medium.com/p/2b3e40a1a124#1b99) подробно описана реализация приложения, с функциями, работающими в фоновом режиме на ОС iOS и Android.